# Correct syntax of using MySQL LIKE?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have query with a bunch of LIKE statenements. I want to optizimze/explain the query, which runs fine. However if I copy this:

```
 SELECT a.*, p.ek, p.vk, p.waehrung, p.onlinepreis
     FROM arts a USE INDEX (i_aktiv, i_iln, i_marke )
         LEFT JOIN pls p ON 
           p.iln = a.iln  
         LEFT JOIN fbs zu 
           ON a.farbe = zu.farbe 
           WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
           AND (
       a.artikelbezeichnung LIKE ? 
    OR a.artikelbezeichnung_lang LIKE ? 
            OR (   a.farbe LIKE '%decke%'
                 OR zu.systemfarbe LIKE '%decke%'
                 OR zu.systemfarbe_en LIKE '%decke%' 
                 )
                                ) 
            )
         ...
```

As parameters I want to add `'%decke%'` but MySQL keeps throwing an error, if I use the `%%`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The error I'm getting is:

you have an error in your SQL-syntax.... check near... %'%'decke%' at OR ( a.farbe LIKE '%decke%' ...

Comment: And the error is ... what, exactly?

Comment: I have used that exact formatting and its worked fine for me.

Comment: ... mh... now it works. I don't get why, probably because it's 3am and I'm turning a little blind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For wildcarded LIKE comparisons, you have to fake it:

```
WHERE somefield LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

wildcarded 'likes' are one place that parameterized queries fall flat on their faces.

Comment: Any proofs? I can't believe or google it. Why parameter cannot be `%foo%` string?

Comment: You can pass in `%foo%` if you like, and that'll work, but then you're having to massage the value of that parameter ahead of time. you can't have `LIKE '%?%'`. That definitely doesn't work.

Comment: @Marc: IMO, that's not an issue of parameterized queries not playing nice with `LIKE` _or_ wildcards. It's just that each bound variable is an independent token, and you can't simply drop it inside a quoted string like that. It'd be akin to saying UDFs fall flat on their faces when it comes to `LIKE`s because you can't do `LIKE '%MyFoo()%'`.

Comment: @Marc B: I agree with Lèse majesté - it's not an issue of parameters or `LIKE` and wildcards. Your answer would confuse newbies, who will just learn that there is some "magic" around this case, while there is nothing special in this case.